# SYMFONY Form TimeType use 1970-01-01 as default date, what is the value to set in the constraint GreaterThanOrEqual?

Tags: php, date, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a `TimeType` field in a Symfony form. In the form `AbstractType` extended class the field looks like this:

```
    $form->add('fieldTime', TimeType::class, array(
        'label' => myLabel,
        'constraints'=>array(
            new GreaterThanOrEqual(array('value'=>date('H:i'))),
            new Time()
        ),
    );
```

The problem is that `date('H:i')` set as value to compare in the constraint `GreaterThanOrEqual`, pick up the actual date like: `2016-02-14 10:15:00`.

Whereas the value received on the `Submit` is like this:

```
DateTime {#12481 ▼
  +"date": "1970-01-01 11:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
}
```

As you see, **it has the time selected by the user but with the 1970 date, hence the constraint is always false**.

I wonder how to either:

- Pass in the constraint `GreaterThanOrEqual` value a time with the
  1970-01-01 date but with the actual time;
- Or how to use the default today date with the time submitted by the user thru the form?

Answer (score -1):

You can [pass "today" to `GreaterThanOrEqual`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/GreaterThanOrEqual.html#comparing-dates), and use a `new DateTime()` to get the complete date, not just the time of the day:

```
$form->add('fieldTime', TimeType::class, array(
    'label' => myLabel,
    'constraints'=>array(
        new GreaterThanOrEqual("today")
    ),
    'data' => new DateTime(),
);
```

Note that "today" is using the server's configured timezone. If you want to specify it, append it to the date string, i.e. "today UTC"

Comment: I ve already tried with 'today' as value in the constraint, it is the same as date('H:i')

Comment: @nyluje The `new DateTime()` should be what you need then.

Comment: Do you mean to change the time submitted in the PRE_SUBMIT event by setting today's date instead of 1970-01-01?

Comment: I've tried to pass 'data' => new DateTime() but when it get submitted it changes the date to 1970-01-01